# loading images through lazylist?

Tags: android, database, simplecursoradapter, lazylist

i'm trying to load some data's to the listview from the offline database in my android application :) 
Here's the problem:
in the database, i stored the link of the imageview. how can i use lazylist with it?!
Here's my codeS:

```
list.setAdapter(null);
            Cursor cursor = dbHelpersamsung.listsamsung();
            String[] columns = new String[] { LebanonSamsung.KEY_URL, LebanonSamsung.KEY_PHONENAME,
                    LebanonSamsung.KEY_PRICE, LebanonSamsung.KEY_MODELNUMBER };

            int[] to = new int[] { R.id.thephoneimage, R.id.title2, R.id.details2,
                    R.id.modelnumber2 };
            SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter2 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this.getSherlockActivity(), R.layout.pricelistoffline,
                    cursor, columns, to, 0);
            list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            list.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
```

How to use lazy list when loading images?? THANKS ALOT :D

Answer (score 0):

here is an interesting thread that can help you : [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for sharing! i know exactly how to load images from list adapter. but what about database?

Comment: Here is a step by step example  http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/asynchronously-populating-listview-from-sqlite-database-using-content-providers/ and an interesting feature http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/queries/